# bind 2 different itemssources to a datagrid in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, datagrid

I would like to bind 2 different Itemssources to a datagrid.
A Datagrid with 4 columns. The first 2 columns should get values from Itemssource1 and the last 2 columns from Itemssource2.

ObservationCollection (MyClass) Itemssource1; MyClass has 2 Properties, like Name and AGE
i can do datagrid.Itemssource= Itemssource1;

but how to bind the Itemssource2, also some ObservationCollection<>, to the Datagrid, so that properties can be used in the 3. and 4. Column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DataGrid can only iterate/manage one item source. Everything is row based and the columns are not that intelligent.

You either need to combine your data into a new object with both sets of fields, or synchronise 2 datagrids side-by-side.

Of the two options simply copying the data into a new collection with a new data type would be the easiest.